# Ajax sends incomplete checkbox value to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code to catch some values checked from inputs.
This is my JavaScript code:

```
var ferestre = $("#ferestre input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

and I send it with `ajax` to php script but if i have 2 words in value like "termopan lemn" then return only the first word "termopan".

Comment: First, `input:checkbox` is redundant - just `:checkbox` will do. Second, check the value of `ferestre` before it goes to the AJAX call to see if it is populated with the correct information

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7FzPR/1/

Comment: @RGraham `input:checkbox` is not redundant - *"..it is recommended to precede it with a tag name or some other selector; otherwise, the universal selector ("\*") is implied."* - [docs](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

Comment: @RGraham From a performance point of view it's not.

Comment: Interesting, makes sense! Will leave my stupid comment in for context and to help the next person who thought the same :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the second checkbox first then only it will return both values

```
var ferestre = $("#ferestre input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
console.log(ferestre);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="ferestre">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="termopan"/>termopan><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="lemn" />lemn    
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tD8D/)

Comment: I cheched the value for ferestre and  show only the first word

Comment: The proble is from the inputs